# Ошибка с обновлением сообщения

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

До недавнего времени все было нормально, но после того, как я обновил вывод сообщения по нажатию на inline кнопки, появилась ошибка

```
aiogram.utils.exceptions.MessageNotModified: Message is not modified: specified new message content and reply markup are exactly the same as a current content and reply markup of the message
```

Я сделал бекап, но ошибка мало того не исчезла, дак и еще по нажатию на другие inline кнопки, мне выводится другой запрос. Если понадобиться, я могу скинуть код, просто мне кажется дело не в нем
Код:
main.py

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
        if str(message.from_user.id) in str(db.get_all_telegram_id()):
            pass
        else:
            db.write_data(message.from_user.id)
        name_clan = message.text[7:]
        if name_clan == '':
            if db.get_nickname(message.from_user.id) == None or db.get_nickname(message.from_user.id) == '':
                    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Привет, этот бот является игрой с элементами из реальной жизни\nПридумай игровой ник\n<i>Его нельзя будет изменить потом</i>', parse_mode='HTML')
                    await New_player.insert_nickname.set()
            else:
                await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'Ваш персонаж:\n\nИмя: <b>{db.get_nickname(message.from_user.id)}</b>\nРодство: <b>{db.get_race(message.from_user.id)}</b>\nКлан: <b>{db.get_name_clan(message.from_user.id)}</b>\nУровень: <b>{db.get_level(message.from_user.id)}</b>', reply_markup=nav.startmenu, parse_mode='HTML')
        else:
            if name_clan not in str(db.get_list_of_clan()):
                await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Привет, этот бот является игрой с элементами из реальной жизни\n<i>Клана, в который вас пригласили, либо не существует, либо его переименовали\nМожете попробовать еще раз, либо начать без клана, для этого придумайте и напишите ник</i>', parse_mode='HTML')
                await New_player.insert_nickname.set()
            else:
                if db.get_nickname(message.from_user.id) != None:
                    db.join_clan(name_clan, message.from_user.id)
                    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'Поздравляю, теперь вы в клане <b>{name_clan}</b>', reply_markup=nav.startmenu, parse_mode='HTML')
                else:
                    db.join_clan(name_clan, message.from_user.id)
                    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                                           text=f'Прежде чем вступить в клан <b>{name_clan}</b> придумайте игровой ник', parse_mode='HTML')
                    #Поздравляю, теперь вы в клане <b>{name_clan}</b>',reply_markup=nav.startmenu, parse_mode='HTML')
                    await New_player.insert_nickname.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=New_player.insert_nickname)
async def insert_nick(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    #('0' or '1' or '2' or '3' or '4' or '5' or '6' or '7' or '8' or '9' in message.text[0]) or
    if (len(message.text) > 15) or message.text[0] == '/':
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, '<i>Ник должен начинатся с буквы, не содержать специальных символов и быть меньше 15 символов\nВведите другой ник</i>', parse_mode='HTML')
    elif message.text in str(db.get_all_nickname()):
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,
                               '<i>Такой ник уже занят\nВведите другой</i>',
                               parse_mode='HTML')
    else:
        db.create_nick(message.text, message.from_user.id)
        await state.finish()
        if db.get_name_clan(message.from_user.id) != 'None' or db.get_name_clan(message.from_user.id) != '':
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'Ну что же, <b>{db.get_nickname(message.from_user.id)}</b>, будем знакомы, но кто ты?', parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=nav.races_choice)
            #await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'Поздравляю, теперь вы в клане <b>{db.get_name_clan(message.from_user.id)}</b>', reply_markup=nav.startmenu, parse_mode='HTML')
        else:
            #await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'Ну что же, <b>{db.get_nickname(message.from_user.id)}</b>, будем знакомы, но кто ты?', parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=nav.races_choice)
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Теперь твое приключение начинается\nДля того, чтобы было веселее можешь вступить или создать свой клан', reply_markup=nav.startmenu)

@dp.callback_query_handler(text=['people', 'elf', 'gnom', 'ork', 'trol', 'goblin', 'drenei', 'demon', 'vampire'])
async def races_choice(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    if call.data == 'people':
        db.write_race('Человек', call.from_user.id)
    elif call.data == 'elf':
        db.write_race('Эльф', call.from_user.id)
    elif call.data == 'gnom':
        db.write_race('Гном', call.from_user.id)
    elif call.data == 'ork':
        db.write_race('Орк', call.from_user.id)
    elif call.data == 'trol':
        db.write_race('Тролль', call.from_user.id)
    elif call.data == 'goblin':
        db.write_race('Гоблин', call.from_user.id)
    elif call.data == 'drenei':
        db.write_race('Дренеи', call.from_user.id)
    elif call.data == 'demon':
        db.write_race('Демон', call.from_user.id)
    elif call.data == 'vampire':
        db.write_race('Вампир', call.from_user.id)
    if db.get_name_clan(call.from_user.id) == None or db.get_name_clan(call.from_user.id) == '':
        await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.from_user.id,
                               text=f'Ваш персонаж:\n\nИмя: <b>{db.get_nickname(call.from_user.id)}</b>\nРодство: <b>{db.get_race(call.from_user.id)}</b>\nКлан: <b>{db.get_name_clan(call.from_user.id)}</b>\nУровень: <b>{db.get_level(call.from_user.id)}</b>',
                               message_id=call.message.message_id, reply_markup=nav.startmenu, parse_mode='HTML')
        await bot.send_message(call.from_user.id,
                               'Теперь твое приключение начинается\nДля того, чтобы было веселее можешь вступить или создать свой клан',)
    else:
        await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.from_user.id,
                                    text=f'Ваш персонаж:\n\nИмя: <b>{db.get_nickname(call.from_user.id)}</b>\nРодство: <b>{db.get_race(call.from_user.id)}</b>\nКлан: <b>{db.get_name_clan(call.from_user.id)}</b>\nУровень: <b>{db.get_level(call.from_user.id)}</b>',
                                    message_id=call.message.message_id, reply_markup=nav.startmenu, parse_mode='HTML')
        await bot.send_message(call.from_user.id,
                               f'Поздравляю, теперь вы в клане <b>{db.get_name_clan(call.from_user.id)}</b>', parse_mode='HTML')

@dp.callback_query_handler(text='start_menu_clan')
async def menu_clan(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    if db.get_name_clan(call.from_user.id) == None or db.get_name_clan(call.from_user.id) == '':
        list_of_clans = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        for i in range(0, len(db.get_list_of_clan())):
            clans = db.get_list_of_clan()[i][0]
            clans = InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'{clans}', callback_data=f'clans{str(i)}')
            list_of_clans.insert(clans)
        back = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Назад', callback_data='back_startmenu')
        list_of_clans.insert(nav.back_startmenu)
        #await message.re
        await call.message.edit_text(f'Ваш персонаж:\nИмя: <b>{db.get_nickname(call.from_user.id)}</b>Родство: <b>{db.get_race(call.from_user.id)}</b>Клан: <b>{db.get_name_clan(call.from_user.id)}</b>Уровень: <b>{db.get_level(call.from_user.id)}</b>', reply_markup=list_of_clans, parse_mode='HTML')
    else:
        await call.message.edit_text(f'Ваш персонаж:\nИмя: <b>{db.get_nickname(call.from_user.id)}</b>Родство: <b>{db.get_race(call.from_user.id)}</b>Клан: <b>{db.get_name_clan(call.from_user.id)}</b>Уровень: <b>{db.get_level(call.from_user.id)}</b>', reply_markup=nav.menu_clan, parse_mode='HTML')

@dp.callback_query_handler(text='back_startmenu')
async def back_start_menu(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    if call.message.content_type == 'venue':
        await call.message.delete()
    else:
        await bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, f'Ваш персонаж:\nИмя: <b>{db.get_nickname(call.from_user.id)}</b>Родство: <b>{db.get_race(call.from_user.id)}</b>Клан: <b>{db.get_name_clan(call.from_user.id)}</b>Уровень: <b>{db.get_level(call.from_user.id)}</b>', reply_markup=nav.menu_clan, parse_mode='HTML')

#Конец стартовое меню
#Меню клана

@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith="clans")
async def clans(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    data = (call.data.title()).lower()
    name = call.message.reply_markup['inline_keyboard'][0]
    for i in range(len(name)):
        if name[i]["callback_data"] == data:
            clan_name = name[i]['text']
            db.join_clan(clan_name=clan_name, telegram_id=call.from_user.id)
            await bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, f'Вы успешно вступили в клан <b>{clan_name}</b>', reply_markup=nav.menu_clan,
                                         parse_mode='HTML')
            break

@dp.callback_query_handler(text='invite_link')
async def invite_link(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.from_user.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text=f'Ссылка для приглашения в клан:\nhttps://t.me/IRL_game_bot?start={db.get_name_clan(call.from_user.id)}', reply_markup=nav.menu_clan)

@dp.callback_query_handler(text='list_of_members')
async def get_list_of_members(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    members_list = [list(i) for i in db.get_members_in_clan(db.get_name_clan(call.from_user.id))]
    members = ''
    for i in members_list:
        members = members + f'{i[0]} {i[1]} {i[2]} Уровень - {i[3]}\n'
    await call.message.edit_text(f'Участники клана <b>{db.get_name_clan(call.from_user.id)}</b>:\n{members}', parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=nav.menu_clan)

#Конец меню клана
#Карта

@dp.callback_query_handler(text='map')
async def map(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    back = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
    back.insert(nav.back_startmenu)
    await bot.send_venue(call.from_user.id, latitude=db.get_all_monsters()[0][1], longitude=db.get_all_monsters()[0][2], title=db.get_all_monsters()[0][0], address='Город', reply_markup=nav.attack_menu)
    await bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, f'Когда доберетесь до монстра, нажмите на кнопку Атаковать для отправки геопозиции\nМонстр убежит через {60 - int(time.time() - float(db.get_all_monsters()[0][3]))} секунд, так что поторопитесь', reply_markup=back)
    await call.message.delete()
    #await bot.send_location(message.id, latitude=57.973026, longitude=56.235289, reply_markup=nav)

@dp.callback_query_handler(text='attack')
async def attack(message: types.Message):
    pass

#Конец карты

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Buttons.py

```
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardRemove

races_choice = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
people = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Человек', callback_data='people')
elf = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Эльф', callback_data='elf')
gnom = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Гном', callback_data='gnom')
ork = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Орк', callback_data='ork')
trol = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Тролль', callback_data='trol')
goblin = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Гоблин', callback_data='goblin')
drenei = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Дренеи', callback_data='Дренеи')
demon = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Демон', callback_data='demon')
vampire = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Вампир', callback_data='vampire')
races_choice.add(people, elf, gnom, ork, trol, goblin, drenei, demon, vampire)

startmenu = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
#clan = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Создать клан', callback_data='clan')
start_menu_clan = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Клан', callback_data='start_menu_clan')
map = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Карта', callback_data='map')
startmenu.add(start_menu_clan, map)

menu_clan = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
list_of_members = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Список участников', callback_data='list_of_members')
invite_link = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Ссылка для приглашения', callback_data='invite_link')
back_startmenu = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Назад', callback_data='back_startmenu')
menu_clan.add(list_of_members, invite_link, back_startmenu)

attack_menu = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
attack = KeyboardButton(text='Атаковать!', request_location=True)
attack_menu.add(attack)
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, если дело не в коде то в чём?

Comment: @ΝNL993 Добавил код

Comment: Какая конкретно кнопка не работает. Ваша ошибка говорит что вы меняете текст на, буквально, тот же что и был.

Comment: @oleksandrigo Не работают, все кнопки клана (включая назад), а так же, когда нажимаю на кнопку Карта, то все равно появляется меню Клана, хотя вроде все CallbackQuery правильные. Я делал бекапы, чтобы сообщения менялись, чтобы ошибка исчезла, но она осталась и еще захватила с собой кнопку Карта.

Comment: Создал чат, будем разбираться https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136892/

Comment: @oleksandrigo У меня нет нужного количества очков репутации :(. Отвечая на ваш вопрос, если человек перешел по реферальной ссылке, в ней содержится метод start='....'. Ну и бот это регистрирует и сразу добавляет человека в клан.

Comment: вы уверены что не можете? Я выставил вам права и у вас должна быть возможность писать

Comment: @oleksandrigo You must have 20 reputation on The Stack Exchange Network to talk here. See the
faq. [https://www.google.ru/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZiuhz-a90zhZoX8d0osKXHaidLf3pZJDMWSg4BVABuZvp02e3YwHko3etNlFL3SdMLJTCB2inliN9MRN_1GMYtJPj2MuhtPqHFbjBqUtXFoAqojYmHJXTaJgPWY8jW9pz9DtPpGpLXuWdsTAZKDoIgifIBGRx4HtrAklgm_1cTXrhOM6LQ87e1eBMmYr3T6ZGEPKrESZVVsCERClzBQvmYXcZxUxTu2_11IOK4SjwC4NIjo79n4Yk2GYschyqS0MZGae6fOVWh348fk1xlsLgEIBmDzKIGlU3n1I4iZqYfh8K3ct-0VB8KOBI1Nn1XXA2SIx2HNT4oK&hl=ru]

Comment: Короче из не самого красивого но в целом рабочего, думаю обернуть все функции типа edit_message в try/except и все будет норм

Comment: Да, просто странно, не могу понять, почему перестало работать, дак и еще затронуло кнопку map